# How to record the last modified time in the comment that was edited in spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

It's easy to record the last modified time in a comment on the cell that was edited (see onEdit() https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers )

But how to record the last modified time of the comment ? 
(if I edit the comment (not a cell) - onEdit() doesn't work )

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google Apps Script doesn't provide an onEdit event for comments/notes, only for the cell values.